# Storing a Image in Same folder in C# Window Form App

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I want to get image form any place,show it in picture box and then save it in the same folder (the project folder). but it gives error .i.e 
    "the Generic error occurred in GDI+."
I have gone through many posts. But I couldn't resolved that problem.
My code is as follow.

```
 private void btnImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
                pictureBox1.Image = bit;
                var imagestudent = pictureBox1.Image;
                string extension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(open.FileName);
                extension += DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss") + Path.GetExtension(open.FileName);

                imagestudent.Save(@"PicturesofStudent\" + extension);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

What should I do?

Comment: Why do you add `//` to the target file name?

Comment: I'm strongly suspecting the filename. You're essentially giving a folder path with the `//`. It probably doesn't exist.

Comment: I think you ment to do is \\ better is to do then  `@"PicturesOfStudent\" + extension`

Comment: "attendance2014-12-21_22_52_31.jpg" this is the filename(extension). the picture folder exist.

Comment: I have tried all ways. both using @ and \\ but it doesn't seem problem to me

Comment: Never post fake code.

Comment: I havn't posted fake code. I have tried the above mentioned methods again. and edited my code to show that they dont work. @HansPassant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you forget to put `.` before file extensions. Try this

```
string extension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(open.FileName);
extension += DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss") + "." + Path.GetExtension(open.FileName);
```

**EDIT**

You might also try [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of calling `PictuteBox.Save` method. :

```
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
    pictureBox1.Image = bit;
    var imagestudent = pictureBox1.Image;
    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(open.FileName) + 
                        DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss") +
                        Path.GetExtension(open.FileName);

    string directory = "PicturesofStudent";
    if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

    File.Copy(open.FileName, Path.Combine(directory, fileName));
}
```

Comment: "attendance2014-12-21_22_52_31.jpg". this is the file name. I think in this there is no need of ".". because it shows .jpg.

Comment: I just added "." in your code snippet and it works without throwing any exception.

Comment: Try `File.Copy` instead of saving image from PictureBox.

Comment: Can you send me link or any other refrence

Comment: string source= Path.GetFullPath(open.FileName); File.Copy(source,Path.Combine("PicturesofStudent\\" , extension),true); but now it says as path not found of PicturesOfStudent\attendance2014-12-21_22_52_31.jpg

Comment: Thankz. I was making folder in solution explorer. Because of that it was not accepting the path. now it creates folder in bin\debug. Thankz